# Mysql Get Max Number of a group than make new group by that max number

Tags: mysql

I have a table, it similar with this table

```
ID Name   Age Status
1  John    32 Life
2  Andre   99 Life
3  Anton   89 Dead
4  Maria   99 Life
5  Mario   13 Life
6  Santi   89 Dead
7  Anggy   56 Dead
8  Amir    99 Life
```

I want to do something like this
1. Group rows by status (Life)
2. Get the max Age from that group (99) (only the max number need)
4. Make new group by age and sort it by ID.

The result will be

```
8   Amir    99  Life
4   Maria   99  Life
2   Andre   99  Life
```

Any way to use only 1 line query for that job? with some (php) data procesing its not to hard to get the result i want, but i want to make code as clean as posible, so maybe i can do that 3 step in just a single query?

Comment: steps 1. and 2. are done in one go. step 3 will join this back to the original table to get the name of the person with those details. write some code for these parts and post the attempt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select id, name, age, status 
    from thetable 
  where age = 
          (select max(age) 
              from thetable 
            where status="Life"
          )
  where status="Life"  
  order by id desc
```

Comment: this will select all the people in the table that have max age (99) but will not check if the status is 'Live' between that subset. It will do it in the selection of the age only

Answer (score 1):

I think the right logic is:

```
select t.id, t.name, t.age, t.status
from table t join
     (select max(t2.age) from table t2 where t2.status = 'life') m
     on t.age = m.age
where t.status = 'life'
order by id desc;
```

Comment: its work thx, but i remove the t2.* and t.* also the m.* things, its ok right?
i go the result i need without that "thing" i realy dont know what is that so i remove, lol,. ty
i used it like this
$sql ="select id, name, age, status from table t join (select max(age) from table where status = 'life') m on age = age where status = 'life' order by id desc";

Comment: @RivoWinrocksLempas . . . You should really leave them in and put your table name where the query has `table`.  But, I think it is ok to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below mentioned query :

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    t4
        CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT 
        MAX(`age`) AS 'age'
    FROM
        t4
    WHERE
        `status` = 'Life') AS t5
WHERE
    `status` = 'Life' AND t4.`age` = t5.age
ORDER BY `id` DESC;
```

Check [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/657f2/1/0)